What is the difference between sysctl_hung_task_timeout_secs and sysctl_hung_task_check_interval_secs
What is the difference between sysctl_hung_task_timeout_secs and sysctl_hung_task_check_interval_secs
Why use sysctl_hung_task_check_interval_secs? Can't sysctl_hung_task_timeout_secs also adjust the monitoring time.
